# What is the resolution to this apparent contradiction?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Momentum is defined as
$$p = \gamma m_0 v$$
And here is another law
$$E^2=(m_0c^2)^2+(pc)^2$$
And [this website](http://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/energy-of-photon) says the energy of a red photon is $1.9074 eV$. Also, light has a rest mass of $0$. The problem is that by the first equation implies momentum is $0$, and then the second equation would imply energy is $0$, and $0 \ne 1.9074 eV$. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The first equation is only valid for massive particles. If you see the formula of the Lorentz factor:

$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

If $v=c$ (the case of massless particles), it is undefined. You can also see as $v \rightarrow c$, $\gamma \rightarrow \infty$, which "compensates" for $m_0=0$.

The second doesn't imply zero energy, because for a photon: $p=h\nu/c$ or equivalently, $E=h\nu$. You can substitute the frecuency of a *red* photon to see if the energy agrees.